# Microsoft Server Backup issue in SBS 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

Good day to all. I recently did a server change and since then the Backup has stopped working. I used Double Take Move for the transfer and server appears to be up fine. I had to re create the Microsoft Backup job and also replace the USB external to a WD 2TB.

The job appears to have run fine the first 2 nights but when I try to test by restoring some files today, I get to the screen where it says Select items to recover and get this error when trying to select the drive volumes: 'Unable to browse (C:). A handle to the driver control device could not be created. Make sure the driver is installed correctly.' Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry forgot to say the server. It is an older HP ML 350 G6 with 2 1TB in RAID 1 running SBS 2008. 32 GB RAM

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this article: http://blog.mpecsinc.ca/2009/11/windows-server-backup-recovery-fail.html

They determine that the cause of the error is a faulty or nonexistent windows system driver, which needs to be reinstalled for the Windows Backup recovery wizard to work.

Following the reinstallation a reboot might be necessary.

Comment: I tried this but did not even see this file as volume driver in system devices when I enabled hidden devices